# .htaccess for without redirection

Tags: .htaccess

By accessing URL http://DOMAIN.COM/rss.php it should load http://DOMAIN.COM/feeds.xml **without redirection**.
Kindly help me if someone know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

> By accessing URL `http://DOMAIN.COM/rss.php` it should load
>  
>   `http://DOMAIN.COM/feeds.xml` without redirection

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !feeds\.xml   [NC]
RewriteRule ^rss\.php/?$    /feeds.xml    [L,NC]
```

Comment: Your `RewriteCond` is kind of pointless =P

Comment: The condition makes sure the requested uri is not `feeds.xml` before applying the rule - however, the rule doesn't attempt to match `feeds.xml`, so the rule would still work perfectly without it.

Comment: Create a test case, there is no loop. It won't match `/feeds.xml` in a second pass because that is a to condition in the `RewriteRule`, not a matching portion of it.

Comment: @Jon. Sorry. My wording was not appropriate. I meant, in the second pass it will map again to `feeds.xml` unless there is something that stops it. But I agree. In this case it wont happen because both are fixed strings. Doesn't hurt to leave it, though. I always include something like that, just in case.

Comment: Ahh, ok =] I guess that makes sense, I just didn't expect to see a fail-safe like that on a rewrite like this. ^^

Comment: @Jon. Thanks for pointing it out, anyway. It is a useful comment.